# horizontal alignment issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

[On my web site](http://www.oreste.parlatano.com/blogger/orest%20e.parlatano.com/blogger/2007/01/pubblica-util%20it-o-videogiochi.html), located at the top right corner I have a radio form field for bathrooms (1+, 2+, 3+, 4+).

In Firefox/Chrome - these all are horizontally aligned on a single line.

However, with IE6+, the bedrooms are split over 2 lines.

Any ideas why this is happening. Seems like a CSS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#search_options TABLE TD
```

This item has a padding-right of 40px. Turn that off and everything should fall back into place.

Your issue also displays in IE8. I used the built in web developer tool to find the issue and to turn off the extra padding.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: If I don't put the padding-right, my columns collide. Any suggestion on how I can keep my columns from colliding (and even keep some whitespace between the two).

Comment: @Hank: Since this solution only replaces one problem with another, you shouldn't mark it accepted, if only because people will stop coming to look at your question.  I only came back because I didn't have time to think about it before and bookmarked it.  @Chris, sorry if that seemed harsh, it WAS a good answer considering that you didn't know about the collision issue.

Comment: IE, older versions like 6 especially, are notoriously evil in their implementations of the standard box model.  Try using "margin" instead of "padding" and see if that helps.  I'd love to give more specific advice about the problem, but your link is no longer working for me, so I can't check it out.